# Execute stored procedure does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure on a DB in MySQL, which is working perfectly, then when i make a copy of it ( navicat data transfer or a sql copy script ), it does not work.

I have an error message:

Procedure execution failed
1264 - Out of range value for column '(null)' at row 1

I check the codes, its the same and the database as well, but on the source DB the stored procedures works but not on the target DB.

I check the users and the right, seems to be same for me.

Any idea how can i debug, find the issue ?

Thanks for your helps

Regards

Comment: Show your sql procedure please

Comment: hi, i added the codes too

Comment: Blag, u thinks its coming from the codes ? i don' t think because its running fine on the source DB

Comment: you have different data in different databases

Comment: Hi GrApDev, I duplicate the datas as well, datas are identical in the 2 databases, as well as the stored procedures

Comment: Try a full export (schema + procedure + data) and import it in a **NEW** DB in both the old and new server. (you can have old declaration / data /table that interfere with your test)

Comment: Hi Blag, that' s i did also, i create new DB and import the script ( schema + procedure + data ). I am thinking that it may be some users rights lock on the stored procedures or db, but don' t know what

Comment: you are aware that mysql spatial extensions makes this SP totally redundant right?

Comment: Hi e4c5, no at all, any data changes if get it installed ?